# Two Flexsliders on same page CSS

Tags: css, flexslider

On [this testpage](http://www.centrumvoorchinesegeneeswijzen.nl/test) I've two Flexsliders working. One at the top (banner) and one as part of an article. Everything is working except the image(s) in the banner doesn't take the full width of the parent div ... or something ... !? I'm overlooking something that's for sure, but my quess is that it has to do with the flexslder.css itself.

Comment: [Please read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it/126000#126000), and also, can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.flexslider .slides {
zoom: 1;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Add max width at line number 45 in flexslider.css

Comment: Thank you all ... it's so obvious, but I did overlook the default max-width:30em of ul ... :%

Comment: welcome @redfox! feel free to contact me if you get any issue in future! :)

Answer (score 0):

below is the class which is apply for maximum width, please remove width.

p, ul, ol, dl, blockquote{max-width:30em}

Answer (score 0):

```
p, ul, ol, dl, blockquote {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.618em;
    margin-bottom: 1.618em;
    max-width: 30em; /* Optimal width for long-form text (depends on font and size!) */
}
```

remove `max-width` in this chunk of code in `chinesegeneeswijzen-global-test.css`  at line no 115

it forces the ul in flexslider to be max-width of 30em